# cakePHP - moved to a sub directory and now the css stylesheets are not working

Tags: cakephp, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

I have moved the entire cakephp site/app (hosted on a windows server) folder to a subfolder called 'data' all is working fine, the app is working fine except for some reason it's not pulling in the css or js files. looking at the  source of the page displayed it shows...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/data/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

I'm not familiar with either cakephp or URL Rewrite rules, would I need to update the Rewrite rules?

The original Cake's root directory was as follows...

```
    define('APP_DIR', 'app');
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));
define('WEBROOT_DIR', 'webroot');
define('WWW_ROOT', ROOT . DS . APP_DIR . DS . WEBROOT_DIR . DS);
```

I have tried the following update...

```
define('APP_DIR', 'app');
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));
define('WEBROOT_DIR', 'webroot');
define('WWW_ROOT', ROOT . DS . APP_DIR . DS . WEBROOT_DIR . DS . 'data' . DS);
```

But with no success.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be carefull with absolute link. You start from /, did your application webroot start in / ?

What I mean is, does your cakephp app/webroot is your root web server directory or not ?

Comment: Can you give me an exemple of url, like the index of your website (change domain to example.com if you want

Comment: interesting, I get a URL Rewrite Module Error....
Module: RewriteModule
Notification: SendResponse
Handler: AboMapperCustom-25921
Error Code: 0x800700b7
Config Error:
Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'rule' with unique key attribute 'name' set to 'Imported Rule 1'
Config File
\\?\C:\Domains\yoursite.com\wwwroot\data\app\webroot\web.config
Requested URL
http://yoursite.com:80/data/app/webroot/css/bootstrap.min.css
Physical Path
C:\Domains\yoursite.com\wwwroot\data\app\webroot\css\bootstrap.min.css
Logon Method: Not yet determined
Logon User: Not yet determined

Comment: Module: RewriteModule Notification: SendResponse Handler: AboMapperCustom-25921 Error Code: 0x800700b7 Config Error: Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'rule' with unique key attribute 'name' set to 'Imported Rule 1' Config File \\?\C:\Domains\yoursite.com\wwwroot\data\app\webroot\web.config Requested URL yoursite.com:80/data/app/webroot/css/bootstrap.min.css Physical Path C:\Domains\yoursite.com\wwwroot\data\app\webroot\css\bootstrap.min.css Logon Method: Not yet determined Logon User: Not yet determined

Comment: What is in C:\Domains\yoursite.com\wwwroot\data\app\webroot\web.config  about collection rule and attribute name ?

Comment: Hi, that is part of the error message I get - I can send you a screen grab? - might help.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25281/discussion-between-elixireu-and-cyril-alfaro)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the helpers to compute for the subfolder:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->css('data/css/bootstrap.min'); ?>
```

Make sure that data/css dir is within the app/webroot/css directory